# Routing Traffic to different instance using ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc, elastic-load-balancer

I have a website hosted on Site Ground let's say www.test.com
I create a subdomain xyz.test.com and routed the traffic to a backend server A through a load balancer which is hosted in a privated subnet in a VPC. It works fine since I have create a listener on which forwards the traffic from 443 to 3000. Now I want to add one backend server B in the same private subnet and want the traffic hitting port 444 of the ELB to be routed to this server.I want the requests xyz.test.com:444 to go to to port 3010 of the server B. In short I want to route traffic to different instances behind a load balancer but my URL is the same just the ports are different.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to setup an [Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html). From the documentation (*emphasis* mine):

> A load balancer serves as the single point of contact for clients. The load balancer distributes incoming application traffic across multiple targets, such as EC2 instances, in multiple Availability Zones. This increases the availability of your application. You add one or more listeners to your load balancer.
>
> A listener checks for connection requests from clients, ***using the protocol and port that you configure***, and forwards requests to one or more target groups, based on the rules that you define. Each rule specifies a target group, condition, and priority. When the condition is met, the traffic is forwarded to the target group. You must define a default rule for each listener, and you can add rules that specify different target groups based on the content of the request (also known as content-based routing).

Some of the benefits that may interested you, over a Classic Load Balancer are:

> - Support for path-based routing. You can configure rules for your
>   listener that forward requests based on the URL in the request. This
>   enables you to structure your application as smaller services, and
>   route requests to the correct service based on the content of the URL.
> - Support for host-based routing. You can configure rules for your listener that forward requests based on the host field in the HTTP
>   header. This enables you to route requests to multiple domains using a
>   single load balancer.
> - Support for routing requests to multiple applications on a single EC2 instance. You can register each instance or IP address with the
>   same target group using multiple ports.
> - Support for registering targets by IP address, including targets outside the VPC for the load balancer.